WinApi - WM_MOUSEMOVE events with the same mouse position
When I handle WM_MOUSEMOVE event I read the mouse position this way:
int mouse_x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
int mouse_y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

I have noticed that sometimes I get events with the same mouse_x and mouse_y in a row. Does exist any rule saying when it happens ?

There are no rules specified when that happens. You just have to be prepared for it. For one, the mouse driver generates mouse positions at a far higher precision than physical screen pixels. A mouse move can thus result in the same physical screen positions. Also: Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?.
